# Placing text in circle

Tags: jquery, css, svg

```
<div id="container">
<div id="circle">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="15vw" height="15vw" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <path id="criclePath"  d=" M 150, 150 m -120, 0 a 120,120 0 0,1 240,0 a 120,120 0 0,1 -240,0 "/>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" fill="none" stroke="#000"/>
    <g>
        <use xlink:f="#criclePath" fill="none"/>
      <text fill="#000" style="font-size: 2.4em; font-weight:900; letter-spacing:-0.03em; text-align:justify">
          <textPath xlink:href="#criclePath">EDUCATION . INSPIRATION . VACATION . </textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gstbopkf/12/)

I would like to place standard text within the circle that is horizontally and vertically centered to the circle. This text must scale along with the circle. Been trying. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`text-anchor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextAnchorProperty) and [`dominant-baseline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#dominant-baseline-property) to do that.

`dominant-baseline` is not supported properly on IE, so you may need to tweak the position manually using `dy` in `em` units, if you need full cross-browser support.

#### [`text-anchor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextAnchorProperty)

> #### middle
>
> The rendered characters are aligned such that the geometric
>   middle of the resulting rendered text is at the initial current text
>   position.

#### [`dominant-baseline`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#dominant-baseline-property)

> #### middle
>
> Use the “middle” baseline: halfway between the alphabetic
>   baseline and the ex-height.

#### [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v3gzfLgj/)

```
<text x="150" y="160" 
      text-anchor="middle"
      dominant-baseline="middle"
      font-size="50">Centering</text>
```

and with `dy`

```
<text x="150" y="160"
      text-anchor="middle"
      font-size="50" 
      dy="0.225em">Centering</text>
```

### Multiple lines

#### [Live Demo with multiple lines](https://jsfiddle.net/v3gzfLgj/2/)

```
<text x="150" y="160" text-anchor="middle" font-size="39">
    <tspan x="150" dy="-0.5em">Centering</tspan>
    <tspan x="150" dy="1em">in ring</tspan>
</text>
```

The first line is up half a line away from the center. The second moves down a whole line. Both in the horizontal center.

#### Bug workaround

#### [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pnrqLx5o/1/)

In Firefox the text in the circle is not aligned correctly, not even close. Here is an alternative way to do the text in the center:

```
<text x="150" y="150" dy="-1.7em"
  fill="#000" font-size="25" text-anchor="middle" 
  letter-spacing="-0.03em">no prior</text>
<text x="150" y="150" dy="-0.6em" 
  fill="#000" font-size="25" text-anchor="middle"
  letter-spacing="-0.03em">knowledge is</text>
<text x="150" y="150" dy="0.6em"
  fill="#000" font-size="25" text-anchor="middle"
  letter-spacing="-0.03em">required for</text>
<text x="150" y="150" dy="1.7em" 
  fill="#000" font-size="25" text-anchor="middle" 
  letter-spacing="-0.03em">beginners</text>
```

[On May 2016, Firefox does not support the `letter-spacing` attribute (yet?)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/letter-spacing#Usage_notes). As is the circle won't justify in Firefox. A quick workaround is to fix the font size to make it work. I might find a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I will definitely need cross-browser compatibility. Also I need to add multiline text. This seems to be a problem with your solution.

Comment: Multiline is done in svg using `<tspan>` children, under the `<text>` element.

Comment: Believe it or not, there is no wordwrap in svg. If you want to cheat, you can put a foreign `div` element in there. That is cheating. You have to wrap it if you want to make an actual svg drawing and not inject a browser `div`.

Comment: Do you need multiline? Do you need wordwrap? Your question didn't say any of that so I didn't go off on a tangent adding a lot of bells and whistles.

Comment: I added multiline to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again!! However, there seems to be a problem with the horizontal alignment of the text lines. In Safari it's sort of okay, but not in FF. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/fx3t5svc/1/

Comment: Okay, I fixed the horizontal problem, fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pnrqLx5o/1/). I'm trying to get the circle to always justify properly now.

Comment: Really great, thank you so much!! It would also be so nice if you could solve the justify issue.

Comment: No good result myself yet in controlling that the text fills out the text path equally cross-browser. So if you have a way, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with a way of specifying all of the offsets, by capturing the positions and orientations from a correct browser and generate the elements explicitly positioned and rotated. Actually calculating the positions and orientations of letters along a bezier curve is not difficult either, but that requires code to run to "fix" it, not ideal.

Comment: Hi Doug, if you have an answer I would be so grateful. Cannot tackle this issue.

Comment: Hello Doug, no luck on the above? If you have a solution I would be very grateful.